# Application failed to install due to signature error

Tags: tizen-native-app

Purchased a Gear Sport watch for Xmas with Tizen 3.0. No problem installing an app from Tizen Studio. Last week I updated to Tizen 4.0.0.2, and now Tizen Studio 3.1 cannot install the app due to certificate error -12:

```
> start process (install) ...... error : -12 error message: :Non trusted
> certificate is used. Register valid certificate:<-32>  end process
> (fail) processing result : Check certificate error [-12] failed spend
> time for pkgcmd is [1377]ms cmd_ret:244
```

Tried removing old certificates and creating new ones without success.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following:

- Delete all old certificates including manually deleting the files in [Install folder]\SDK-data\keystore.
- Uninstall Extension SKDs from Package Manager.
- In Package Manager -> Configure, click Extension SDK and turn on Samsumg Certificate Extension and Samsumng Wearable Extension.
- Install Extensions SKDs of interest + Samsung Certificate and Wearable Extensions.
- Create a new Samsung certificate, selecting "Use an existing author certificate" in Advanced options, providing the certificate from C:\Users[user account]\SamsungCertificate[certificate name]